# Cannot download the application. The application is missing the required files

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, clickonce

Using Visual Studio ClickOnce for publishing an app. I have a NAS that the app is published to. The folder has read only permission for everybody. We are getting the following error:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 10.0.17134.0 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
clr.dll             : 4.7.3394.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
dfdll.dll           : 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
dfshim.dll          : 10.0.17134.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SOURCES
Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/erics/Downloads/xxxxxxxx.application

ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of C:\Users\erics\Downloads\xxxxxxxx.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Downloading file:///C:/Users/erics/Downloads/xxxxxxxx.application did not succeed.
    + Could not find file 'C:\Users\erics\Downloads\xxxxxxxx.application'.
    + Could not find file 'C:\Users\erics\Downloads\xxxxxxxx.application'.
    + Could not find file 'C:\Users\erics\Downloads\xxxxxxxx.application'.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
* [5/6/2019 8:53:47 AM] : Activation of C:\Users\erics\Downloads\xxxxxxxx.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [5/6/2019 8:53:48 AM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
    - Downloading file:///C:/Users/erics/Downloads/xxxxxxxx.application did not succeed.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Net.WebException
    - Could not find file 'C:\Users\erics\Downloads\xxxxxxxx.application'.
    - Source: System
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Net.WebException
    - Could not find file 'C:\Users\erics\Downloads\xxxxxxxx.application'.
    - Source: System
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
        at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException
    - Could not find file 'C:\Users\erics\Downloads\xxxxxxxx.application'.
    - Source: mscorlib
    - Stack trace:
        at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
        at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
        at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
        at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
        at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.
```

I have check all my deployment paths and they are correct and reachable.

I have changed the folder permission to read/write and that did not resolve the issue.

I have checked for the presence of xxxxxxxx.application and it is present in the version folder.

I have checked for the absense of any files called out in the manifest. They are all in the version folder.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Can you share your manifest file?

Comment: More info. It **WILL** install correctly if the user browses directly to the setup.exe file and run that. IT does not install correctly using Chrome browser when clicking and downloading from the web page that ClickOnce automatically builds. It **might** be installing OK when using Edge browser - not sure yet - not enough tries on different computers.